# Circular type dependency deadlock in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Let `Foo` and `Bar` be types. `Foo` has a `Bar bar` member, and `Bar` has a `Foo foo` member:

```
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

struct Foo { Bar bar; };
struct Bar { Foo foo; };
```

This can not compile, since `Foo` must be defined for `Bar` to be defined, but `Foo` cannot be defined until `Bar` is defined - a deadlock.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: No.  You cannot have this.  What would the size of `Foo` be?

Comment: Much like tic-tac-toe and thermonuclear war, the only way to win is not to play. In C++, an object cannot contain an instance of itself, either directly or - as in the example - indirectly.

Comment: Either Foo, or Bar, or both, could contain a reference or pointer to the other class.  The compiler knows the size required for a pointer or reference. This is the standard approach for breaking such dependencies.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: is there a standard solution or design pattern to address this?  FWIW, I'm coming to C++ from Python, which does allow this.

Comment: `Foo` could contain a pointer to `Bar`. Otherwise, you'd end up with a `Foo` containing a `Bar` containing a `Foo` containing a `Bar`... ad infinitum. There's no computer in the world that could hold such a structure in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The almighty standard:

§ 9.2/9

> Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. In
>   particular, a class C shall not contain a non-static member of class
>   C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C.

And:

§ 9.2/19

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its
>   address is the same as the address of its first non-static data
>   member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first
>   base class subobject (if any).

Comment: Umm, won't the `unique_ptr` here lead to a problem on deletion?  Both `Foo` and `Bar` own each other, so `Foo` will try to delete `Bar`, which will try to delete `Foo`...

Comment: @Oli For the moment I've removed the part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following scheme (i.e., use pointers instead of concrete objects):

```
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

struct Foo 
  {
  Bar *bar; 
  };
struct Bar 
  {
  Foo *foo; 
  };
```

And allocate/deallocate `bar` and `foo` appropriately in your code.

Reason: Although you forward declare your structs the compiler doesn't have any clue how to allocate the `Bar` concrete object in your `Foo` struct since it hasn't seen `Bar`'s reference yet.